# Create functions at Run Time Or dispatch Right Function

Tags: c++, function, runtime

I have a situation i don't know how to exactly define it.
I have regular expression functions that allow me to extract specific patterns from text:
In total I have 9 functions:

```
bool extractDate(const char *);
bool extractHeureFax(const char*);
bool extractFaxPhone(const char*);
bool extractFormePolitesse(const char*);
bool extractCodePostal(const char*);
bool extractDate2(const char*);
bool extractTelephone2(const char*);
bool extractNumbers(const char*);
bool extractalphanumeric(const char*);
bool extractnumeric(const char*);
bool extractPageNumber(const char*);
```

The problem is that Each time that they want to add a regular expression they have to modify the **Whole** **CODE** which is not a very good idea.

One of their solution was to put all the regular expression in a text file. So each time
that they want to add a new regular expression they can add it to the text file, and load them at run time.
Every Regular expression in the text contains the ID and RE
**Example:**

```
DATE: ^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])([\\.\\-\\/\\ ])([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])([\\.\\-\\/\\ ])([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
HEURE: ([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
TELEPHONE: ^(01|02|03|04|05|06|08)(([\\.\\-\\/\\ ])?[0-9][0-9]){4}
FORMULE POLITESSE: ^((c|C)ordialement|Sinc(è|\u00E8)rement|Sinc(è|\u00E8)re|croire|agr(é|\u00E9)er|agreer|l'expression|distingu(é|\u00E9)s|sentiments|salutations|consid(e|é|\u00E9)ration)$
CODE POSTAL: ^((0[1-9])|([1-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])|(2A)|(2B))[0-9]{3}$
```

Then save the text in a vector and try all the Regular expressions until the right one is found.

**Inside the code:**
That's how I handle the functions

```
                    if(extractDate(e->getName().c_str()))
                    {

                        e->setType(0);

                    }

                    else if(extractHeureFax(e->getName().c_str()))
                    {

                        e->setType(1);
                        //  int x0 = e->getXCenter();
                        //  int y0 = e->getYCenter();
                        //  markPoints(xmlFile,x0,y0,20,0,255,0);
                    }
                    //TELEPHONE = BLEU
                    else if(extractFaxPhone(e->getName().c_str()))
                    {
                        e->setType(2);

                    }

                    else if(extractCodePostal(e->getName().c_str()))
                    {
                        e->setType(3);

                    }
```

ExtractDAte(), ExtractHeureFax() etc.. are the regular expression functions:

```
bool Keywords::extractCodePostal(const char * code)
{
    // cout <<"code postal"<<endl;
    const boost::regex e("^((0[1-9])|([1-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])|(2A)|(2B))[0-9]{3}$");
    return boost::regex_match(code,e);
}///end function


bool Keywords::extractDate2(const char*date2)
{
    const boost::regex e("((j|J)anvier|(f|F)\u00E9vrier|(f|F)évrier|(f|F)evrier|(m|M)ars|(a|A)vril|(m|M)ai|(j|J)uin|(j|J)uillet|juillet|(a|A)o\u00FBt|(a|A)oût|aout|(s|S)eptembre|(o|O)ctobre|(n|N)ovembre|(d|D)\u00E9cembre|(d|D)écembre|(d|D)ecembre|JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE)");
    return boost::regex_match(date2,e);
}///end function
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to **UPDATE** or **ADD** functions. without having to change the code. Is what I explained corret?
I am also looking at VTable, I don't know if it can solve the problem

Comment: Well if you want to avoid compiling your application when you modify your regex's not hardcoding them is a good start. Everything else, e.g. if your code can automatically recognize and apply new expressions depends heavily on your use case

Comment: @user2573221 Check my code please. You can See How I extract the patterns and the functions I use. Do you think that I can Use One extract Function that can Send me to the right Regular expression?

Comment: I can Use the text of course. But I want to see If i can do it in a better way.
EACH TIME that i want to add a regular expression I have to add AN ELSE IF condition ...

Comment: Ok, so what you need is a way to map a string to a number based on regular expressions.  It should work to have a file that lists the regular expressions along with the number that you want to return if the string matches that regular expression.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato yes I see. that's what I was thinking about:
Number1 RE1
Number2 RE2